# Banno EULA not displaying in iOS

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are going live with our first Plugin and we need to link to the Banno EULA on the consent page. We have utilized the 'View public EULA' found under settings in Banno People. This works on devices other than iOS. We receive an error. Is there a way to fix the issue we are experiencing? Tried downloading versions and still experience same results.

Attached link: https://banno.com/a/eula/d4cc1010-15e8-11e9-8ebd-acde48001122
When opening in iOS the message below appears. Also downloading to new version produces same results.
[image]

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug in browser handling on iOS, given that I can reproduce the problem in Safari and Chrome on an iPhone. However, the page shows fine in Safari on iPadOS. We've notified Engineering about this issue.

Comment: The problem can be reproduced without needing to show it in a plugin. I can reproduce the problem simply by visiting https://banno.com/a/eula/d4cc1010-15e8-11e9-8ebd-acde48001122 on an iPhone.

Comment: Has there been any update related to a fix for the bug? Testing resulted in the same issue on iPhone. @JaimeLopezJr.

Comment: Engineering thinks it may be a few weeks away from untangling some things for a fix.

Comment: hopefully you saw the update (with answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engineering has released a fix as of January 19, 2023 for this issue.